# Oracle: Create a hidden user for RMAN backups only

Tags: oracle-11g, rman

It's been a long time since I worked with Oracle and I can't remember whether the following is possible:

I'm trying to create a hidden DBA user [ alternatively do this process as root user ] to perform complete and differential backups on Oracle 11g with RMAN. I cannot use the "SYS" user, because I don't have the password and I don't want to change it.

The sole purpose for the hidden user is to have complete db backups in case of a problem, since we suspect the software company that should be providing us with servicing our application and db of damaging the database, either out of sheer incompetence or on purpose. We don't care which it is, our company needs to be able to fix such issues ASAP so that we can work while the software provider sorts out their problems in their own time. But the only type of backup they do is a db dump and it's insufficient.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "hidden", but yes, you can definitely create another user, setup it's roles specifically aimed at backup ... it'll be visible just like any other user though.

Comment: so what happens when you open a command line and type in RMAN when logged in as a user who is a member of ORA_DBA?

Comment: Basically I have a bunch of errors when running SHOW ALL; or target / . 
What seems to work [ I only thought of trying it out a minute ago and did ] is % rman target /
Now I have to figure out, how to edit output folders and similar settings, once I do that, I'll run the first complete db backup and will go home hoping that in the morning I can validate the backup. And no, I'm not really an Oracle admin as such. But I have to do it, so I will

Comment: While this question was answered, I'll welcome any additional remarks and notes.

Comment: You should ask a new question about how to do RMAN backups complete with the details of what storage you have available to back up, how big is the database, what is the expectation for loss of data (ie unwilling to loose more than an hour of data entry implies taking backup and moving logs off the server every hour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do RMAN backups you need the [SYSDBA or SYSOPER roles](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/dba.htm#sthref137). In order to grant those you need to be able log on as a user with those roles: ie the SYS role.

There are variations where you use OS authentication or if your OS user is a member of the ORA_DBA group.

Easiest is if you can do this:

```
CONNECT / AS SYSDBA
```

from the server then you can run an RMAN script like

```
RMAN> BACKUP AS BACKUPSET DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
```

This very basic script should be configured with details particular to your setup such as the location to backup the files to, crosscheck existing backups, etc.

Comment: This helped a lot, I ended up using the root user, once I successfully connected RMAN to the DB.

But I also ended up having to shut down the database, because ARCHIVELOG wasn't configured and I needed full cold backup. 

My next step will be configuring an RMAN script which will contain a separate configuration for backup location and similar. 

The absolute horror I felt when I found out, that the company we pay staggering fees for their services never:
1) Configured RMAN
2) Did RMAN backup 
was enough for me to realize, that I'll probably will have to learn RMAN from scratch to do the job